# Java installation in chrome and windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, java

I am using Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64 m and trying to install Java 7 update 21.

When trying to install Java on my Windows 8 PC - I get pop-up window that ends the process. It states that the feature I am trying to use is on a network resource and is unavailable. Then it states Click OK and try again - It is showing me a default path for the source as:

`\Tim\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\jre1.7.0_13\`

I'm not sure what to do to install Java.

Comment: Which version did you try to install, 32 or 64-bit? Ensure the installer isn't corrupt and Chrome is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing it from a site like [Ninite](http://ninite.com)? For example, [this installer](http://ninite.com/java/ninite.exe) should automatically install Java

Comment: Fava beans != Java beans! ;D

Comment: @karan no, I didn't notice that my phone put fava in there by accident